# Logging in NAS with python

Tags: python, nas

I have a script that moves newly dowloaded video files from the "torrent" folder to a remote folder on a QNAP (NAS) device that I have on my network.

Problem: to run this script I first have to manually log in into the NAS (windows 7 prompts me for username and password the first time I want to access this network device) and the the script can do it's work.

Is there a way to make the python script log-in automatically?

Answer (score 3):

Ok, it seems this was simpler than I tought:

```
os.system(r"NET USE P: \\<SERVER IP>\<PATH> %s /USER:%s" % (password, user_name))
```

After you finish your stuff:

```
os.system(r"NET USE P: /DELETE")
```

Thanks anyways...

Comment: Have you run into any issues with being prompted with a y/n dialog for force closing the drive when files are open?